# How to maintain the aspect ratio when using GPUImage?

Tags: aspect-ratio, gpuimage

I found the Instagram has a camera window like 300*300？ its a square, then Im trying to use the GPUImage to make the same camera size.so I wrote like this:

```
primaryView = [GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                   CGRectMake(0,0,300,300)];//define a square view

//define a still camera
stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc]
              initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480
              cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];

//make it portrait
stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

//define a filter
filter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];

//force the output to 300*300
[filter forceProcessingAtSize:((GPUImageView*)self.primaryView).sizeInPixels];

//set things up
[stillCamera addTarget: filter];
[filter addTarget: primaryView];
[stillCamera startCameraCapture];
```

Now I really get a square view..but the view looks so flat, its completely distortion, I think it might be something wrong with the aspect ratio.then I set the fill mode of the primary view like this:

```
[primaryView setFillMode:kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill];
```

then this:

```
[primaryView setFillMode:kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio];
```

then this:

```
[primaryView kGPUImageFillModeStretch];
```

FINALLY! none of these work..so what I am missing, any one, help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-forceProcessingAtSize:` causes that filter to output an image of exactly the size you provide, ignoring aspect ratio. That squishes your image into a 300x300 square.

If you want to preserve the aspect ratio of your image, you'd want to use `-forceProcessingAtSizeRespectingAspectRatio:`.

However, that will letterbox your image. To replicate what Instagram does, you probably want to instead cut a square region out of the center of the image. For that, use a crop filter with a square aspect ratio.

Comment: That did answer my question! Thank you Brad! I read a lots about GPUImage written by you.