# high memory usage when resizing uiimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8.1

Heavy memory usage when resizing and drawing UIImage in rect.

```
   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        UIImage *selectedImage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        //  COMPRESSING IMAGE
     NSData   *selectedImageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 0.5);
        UIImage *selectedImageFromData=[UIImage imageWithData:selectedImageData];


        //SCALING UIIMAGE
        UIImage *scaledImage=[[UIImage alloc]init];
        if (((selectedImageFromData.size.width>3264) && (selectedImageFromData.size.height>2448)) || ((selectedImageFromData.size.height>3264) && (selectedImageFromData.size.width>2448)))
        {
           CGFloat originalWidth=selectedImageFromData.size.width;
                CGFloat originalHeight=selectedImageFromData.size.height;
                CGFloat myWidth=2048;
                CGFloat widthRatio=myWidth/originalWidth;
                CGFloat dynamicHeight=widthRatio*originalHeight;

         CGImageRef CoreGraphicsImage=selectedImageFromData.CGImage;
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(CoreGraphicsImage);
        CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo=CGImageGetBitmapInfo(CoreGraphicsImage);
  CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(CoreGraphicsImage);

        CGContextRef context=CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, myWidth, dynamicHeight, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(CoreGraphicsImage), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(CoreGraphicsImage), colorSpace, bitmapInfo);


        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, myWidth, dynamicHeight), CoreGraphicsImage);
        CGImageRef CGscaledImage=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
        UIImage *CGLastimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGscaledImage];


        NSLog(@"%f",CGLastimage.size.width);
        NSLog(@"%f",CGLastimage.size.height);

        VisualEffectImageVIew.image=CGLastimage;
                BackgroundImageView.image=CGLastimage;
                ForegroundImageView.image=CGLastimage;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@" HEIGHT %f",selectedImageFromData.size.height);
            NSLog(@" WIDTH %f",selectedImageFromData.size.width);

        VisualEffectImageVIew.image=selectedImageFromData;
        BackgroundImageView.image=selectedImageFromData;
        ForegroundImageView.image=selectedImageFromData;
        }
       if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {


            [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

            [self popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:popoverController];
      }

    }
```

Here's an image below, in the image you can see the above mentioned code is using too much memory. Would like to know why it's using too much memory and would appreciate any solutions.

[image]

Comment: Just because you load a JPEG in a UIImage doesn't mean it doesn't have to decode every pixel of the image, and store it in memory. FYI, 3200x2400 px = 7.68Mpix, in RGB (24 bits per pixel) this yields 184.32MBits, or about 23Mbytes.

Comment: Yes but how does it relate to my problem? Here we are trying to scale down images that are more than 8 megapixels.And we not only have memory issues at time we get app crashes too.For more info check the code in the image above which is using heavy memory .

Comment: Just saying it's normal that resizing megapixel images takes so much RAM. As stated in the answers, you should definitely use some optimized library like GPUImage.

Comment: we'll look into that then.

Comment: Is there a way to use GPUImageView in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to images, i've always been a big fan of [Brad Larson's GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage), it can do anything you want and uses GPU instead of CPU, which leave you with plenty of power to avoid crashes due to memory pressure.

And also it's pretty good.

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783357/how-to-maintain-the-aspect-ratio-when-using-gpuimage) might also help you achieve what you want once you're done setting up the project.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using CPU for drawing data into a frame, i suggest you use CGImage for draw in GPU Context

```
- (UIImage *) scaleToSize: (CGSize)size
{
    // Scalling selected image to targeted size
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width, size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));

    if(self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight)
    {
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, -M_PI_2);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -size.height, 0.0f);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.height, size.width), self.CGImage);
    }
    else
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), self.CGImage);

    CGImageRef scaledImage=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: scaledImage];

    CGImageRelease(scaledImage);

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at our updated code, the CoreGraphics is faster but memory Warnings and Crashes have become even more now.(Memory report Shows 150 MB usage now ).App Crashes when resizing next(second) Image.ALL I WANT TO SAY IS ITS BECOME EVEN WORSE NOW.

Comment: Sorry it's not fast it's the same